# Convergence in probability and inequality

Tags: convergence

Is it true that if
$$ 0 \leq x_n \leq y_n \xrightarrow{p} 0,$$ 
then 
$$x_n \xrightarrow{p} 0?$$
If this is true, I would be very grateful if you could give me some references where I can find the proof.

Comment: This follows directly from the *definition* of convergence in probability (and monotonicity of an arbitrary measure).

Comment: Try to prove it yourself: Use _reductio ad absurdum_ i.e. start by assuming that $x_n \xrightarrow{p} c,\; c>0$. And "translate" the symbol $\xrightarrow{p}$ into its full notation.

Comment: Hi, @Alecos. I fear I must be misinterpreting your comment. How would your argument help? At least conceivably, $X_n$ might not converge at all or might converge to a nondegenerate random variable, neither of which seem covered by that line of argument. I would work directly from the definition, exhibit a simple set inclusion, and call it a day. :-)

Comment: Hi @cardinal. I guess I "read" into the OP's formulation that $x_n$ is by assumption always sandwiched between $0$ and $y_n$. Then one could start by assuming also these cases that you mention -although the day would last longer this way!:)... except if I am forgetting something basic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $Y_n$ tends to $0$ in probability if 
$$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} P(\omega:|Y_n(\omega)| <\epsilon) = 1 \, ,
$$
for every $\epsilon>0$. Since $0\leq X_n\leq Y_n$, by hypothesis, if $|Y_n|<\epsilon$, then $|X_n|<\epsilon$, yielding that
$$
  \{\omega:|Y_n(\omega)|<\epsilon\} \subset \{\omega:|X_n(\omega)|<\epsilon\} \, .
$$
Please, make sure that the inclusion above is totally clear. Now, using the [monotonicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Monotonicity) of $P$, can you relate the probabilities of the two events above? What does this relation imply for $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\omega:|X_n(\omega)|<\epsilon)$? [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties) may help.